System.Text.Json.JsonException in System.Text.Json.dll Error deserializing ../Data\clients.json: The JSON value could not be converted
I am working on an ASP.NET Core project to migrate data from multiple JSON files into an SQLite database. Below is the DataMigration class I wrote for this purpose:
using System.Text.Json;

namespace CargoHub
{
    public class DataMigration
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;

        public DataMigration(AppDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _context = dbContext;
        }

        public async Task<List<string>> MigrateData(string folder = "../Data")
        {
            var processedFiles = new List<string>();
            var jsonFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder);

            foreach (var jsonFile in jsonFiles)
            {
                try
                {
                    await ProcessFile(jsonFile);
                    processedFiles.Add(jsonFile);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error processing {jsonFile}: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }

            return processedFiles;
        }

        private async Task ProcessFile(string filePath)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);

            switch (fileName)
            {
                case "clients":
                    var clients = await DeserializeJson<List<Client>>(filePath);
                    await SaveToDatabase(clients);
                    break;

                // Uncomment to handle more file types
                // case "inventories":
                //     var inventories = await DeserializeJson<List<Inventory>>(filePath);
                //     await SaveToDatabase(inventories);
                //     break;

                case "item_groups":
                    var itemGroups = await DeserializeJson<List<ItemGroup>>(filePath);
                    await SaveToDatabase(itemGroups);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private async Task<List<T>> DeserializeJson<T>(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                var jsonData = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(filePath);
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(jsonData)!;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error deserializing {filePath}: {ex.Message}");
                return new List<T>();
            }
        }

        private async Task SaveToDatabase<T>(List<T> entities) where T : class
        {
            if (entities.Count == 0) return;

            _context.AddRange(entities);
            int changedRows = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(changedRows);
        }
    }
}

Here's the Client model that represents the structure of the clients.json file:
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace CargoHub
{
    public class Client : BaseModel
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string? Name { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("address")]
        public string? Address { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("city")]
        public string? City { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("zip_code")]
        public string? ZipCode { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("province")]
        public string? Province { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("country")]
        public string? Country { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("contact_name")]
        public string? ContactName { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("contact_phone")]
        public string? ContactPhone { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("contact_email")]
        public string? ContactEmail { get; set; }
    }
}

The BaseModel class looks like this:
namespace CargoHub
{
    public class BaseModel
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("created_at")]
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("updated_at")]
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }
}

Here is an example of the clients.json file I am trying to process:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Raymond Inc",
        "address": "1296 Daniel Road Apt. 349",
        "city": "Pierceview",
        "zip_code": "28301",
        "province": "Colorado",
        "country": "United States",
        "contact_name": "Bryan Clark",
        "contact_phone": "242.732.3483x2573",
        "contact_email": "robertcharles@example.net",
        "created_at": "2010-04-28 02:22:53",
        "updated_at": "2022-02-09 20:22:35"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Williams Ltd",
        "address": "2989 Flores Turnpike Suite 012",
        "city": "Lake Steve",
        "zip_code": "08092",
        "province": "Arkansas",
        "country": "United States",
        "contact_name": "Megan Hayden",
        "contact_phone": "8892853366",
        "contact_email": "qortega@example.net",
        "created_at": "1973-02-24 07:36:32",
        "updated_at": "2014-06-20 17:46:19"
    }
]

The Issue
Even though I named all the properties in my Client class to match the JSON structure, I still encounter issues when deserializing the data. Specifically, some fields are not being populated correctly.
I have already tried removing the [JsonPropertyName] attributes, but the problem persists.
What could I be missing in the deserialization process, or is there something else wrong with my approach?
Any help would be appreciated!

Your dates are in the wrong format - don't you see an exception telling you this?

I am confident that the issue is related to the created_at and updated_at fields. The way they are formatted does not comply with the format required by the DateTime object.
Either update their values to adhere to the ISO 8601 standard of the DateTime or implement custom serialization logic to handle their current format.
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime?>
{
    private const string DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    public override DateTime? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(reader.GetString(), DateTimeFormat, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out var dateTime))
            {
                return dateTime;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime? value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value.HasValue)
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(value.Value.ToString(DateTimeFormat));
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteNullValue();
        }
    }
}

and use it like :
[JsonPropertyName("created_at")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }

Or this in DB :
UPDATE clients
SET 
    created_at = strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', created_at) || 'Z',
    updated_at = strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', updated_at) || 'Z'
WHERE 
    created_at IS NOT NULL AND updated_at IS NOT NULL;

up to you which way you choose.

I'd hesitate to upvote this answer. Although it would work, (1) if at all possible the JSON should be using a date format that will be parseable by all users, not just this one, and (2) You should most definitely not ever be storing date times in the database as strings.
